# Can't a Macbook Pro work properly on integrated GPU only?

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, gpu

For a couple of weeks, I've been having kernel panics in my MacBook Pro (Early 2011, Yosemite), mostly doing zoom operations using QuickView and Preview.

A couple of times, it had problems rebooting, until finally it only rebooted to a grey screen.

I installed gfxCardStatus to prevent it to switching to the discrete GPU at any time, and things seemed to go smoothly for a couple of days. But one day it had a kernel panic when waking up from sleep.

Booting in verbose mode showed no indications of what the problem could be, but I suspected it was a video card issue. I've known that this model of MBP had problems with defective AMD Radeon discrete GPUs. I know Apples is repairing eligible machines, but I live in a country where perhaps that wouldn't be possible.

I decided to prevent the laptop from using the AMD GPU and use the integrated intel chip instead, I moved this drivers out of the `/System/Library/Extensions/`folder:

```
AMD2400Controller.kext
AMD2600Controller.kext
AMD3800Controller.kext
AMD4600Controller.kext
AMD4800Controller.kext
AMD5000Controller.kext
AMD6000Controller.kext
AMD7000Controller.kext
AMD8000Controller.kext
AMD9000Controller.kext
AMDFramebuffer.kext
AMDRadeonVADriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX3000.kext
AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX4000.kext
AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver.bundle
AMDSupport.kext
ATIRadeonX2000.kext
ATIRadeonX2000GA.plugin
ATIRadeonX2000GLDriver.bundle
ATIRadeonX2000VADriver.bundle
```

It wouldn't boot up after that either, so I moved this ones also:

```
GeForce.kext
GeForceGA.plugin
GeForceGLDriver.bundle
GeForceTesla.kext
GeForceTeslaGLDriver.bundle
GeForceTeslaVADriver.bundle
GeForceVADriver.bundle
```

**After that it did boot up**, but the screen shows thin horizontal blue stripes all over as well as some other glitches and overall sluggishness.

Detail of stripes (there's some unavoidable Moire pattern in the photo, but the thin blue lines can be appreciated in the darker parts):
[image]

I just want my Mac to use the integrated Intel GPU and forget the discrete ADM Radeon card altogether. **Other machines, including Apple machines, don't have a discrete GPU, just an integrated one, and they work fine for day-to-day, non-graphic-intensive tasks**

**My question:**

- Is possible for this machine to work normally using only the integrated Intel GPU?
- If so, how?
- Are both my discrete GPU and my integrated GPU damaged?**

Answer (score 1):

Just moving kext files won't disable your discrete graphics card, it will just make it work in a very basic mode.

You can achieve that modifying certain EFI variable. I answered [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285896/94184) with the full procedure to permanently disable discrete graphics card on startup and have a fully functional machine.

Answer (score 0):

That seems not to be going well.

First check this out: http://www.apple.com/ca/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Next I would suggest:

put all ATI/AMD drivers back to /System/Library/Extensions/

- remove only and specifically the driver files that were being used for the specific GPU. In your case:

  sudo rm -r /System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX3000*
- sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions
- reboot

Comment: Do you mean AMDRadeonX3000* ?

Comment: I did this http://www.asyncro.com/2014/03/24/macbook-pro-discreate-graphics-card-issue-fix-updated/ and damaged the kernel cache, not it won't boot even in single user mode (command-s). What can I do now?

Comment: now you are a candidate for system restore :) cmd+r

Comment: I'm out of luck. cmd+r boots into a grey screen (after a pin-striped Apple logo and about a third of progress bar)

Comment: do you have a bootable USB

Comment: The problem is that any installer will try to use the discrete GPU and it is damaged. After my last comment O tried again and the recovery started from the recovery partition but it used the discreta Radeon GPU and first the image was shifted, then with vertical blue bands then nothing at all (during downloading). Afterthat I had to turn the computer off sinces I couldn,t see is the installer was prompting me for anything.

Comment: It should be working in safe mode that does not requires discrete GPU but as last resort, wipe that disk and start over.