# MacBook Pro 15-inch booting halts and its screen becomes green

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

The scenario is:

1. I cannot log in Mac OSX if booting normally as the booting halts and the screen becomes green with nothing else on it.
2. In Recovery mode, reinstall Sierra and previous EI Capitan, but the problem still exists. ( Actually, this problem happened at EI Capitan first more than one year ago, and later I upgraded it to Sierra and tried to fix it, but it did not.)
3. Erase the Mac OSX partition, and reinstall Sierra, but the problem still exists.
4. I can log in Safe mode ( Shift ).
5. I can log in Recovery mode ( Command + R ).
6. I can log in Windows in Bootcamp.

My laptop details are below.

1. MacBook Pro 15-inch, Early 2011
2. Graphics: (1)AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB (2) Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB
3. Processor: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
4. Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
5. Hard drive: Samsung SSD 750G
6. System: Sierra, 10.12.5

This problem has blocked me more than one year, and I have tried many ways, but none of them worked.

Is there anyone can help me fix it?

[image: Before becoming green]

[image: After becoming green]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/310597/edit) your question to further expand on what you mean by the screen becomes green? Is it just a green screen with nothing else on it? At what point does the screen turn green? Perhaps you can add a photo to your question. Also, are you saying your MBP boots totally fine in Safe Mode and you can use it, but just not when you try to boot normally? If so, have you installed anything else or migrated any data from a Time Machine backup after reinstalling macOS?

Comment: I updated my questions. In addition, after reinstall macOS, I did not install anything, did not migrate any data from a backup.

Comment: Ok, so is the *current* state a MBP with a freshly installed macOS Sierra and no other data or installations?

Comment: Yes, at the moment, nothing else except the Sierra. But before when there were some other data, the problem was still the same. As I said, this problem has blocked me more than one year. Only recently, I erased the mac osx partition, and reinstalled Sierra only. I thought erasing the partition might fix the problem, but actually it did not.

Comment: Ok, this is where it's a little confusing. When you say *I erased the mac osx partition, and left Sierra only*, what do you mean? Do you mean you erased the partition and then *reinstalled* Sierra? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, correct. I edited my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70981/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-jeff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after referring to the following link:
[MacBook Pro: How to disable discrete GPU permanently from EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi)

Below are my steps.

1. MUST log in Recovery mode rather than Single user mode or any    other mode.
2. Open a console.
3. nvram    fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
4. Move AMD* files according to the following steps:
   (a) cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ SSD
   (b) mkdir AMD_Kexts
   (c) mv System/Library/Extensions/AMD*.* AMD_Kexts/
   (d) reboot
   (e) option+command+p+r (Reset NVRAM)

Now I can log in the regular mode successfully. Although sometimes there are some strips and "afterglow" artefacts, it is still better than what happens in the safe mode which is so slow and loses many video and audio features.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when a problem **is not** occurring when booted into Safe Mode, but occurs when booting normally, it's time to investigate login items, fonts, and kernel extensions.

Based on what you've already tried, your scenario seems a little different to this, so I'd try creating a new additional Admin account to see if you can log into this normally.

**Create an additional Admin account**

You can do this by tricking your MBP into thinking it's being set up as new:

1. Boot into Single User Mode by restarting your Mac and pressing and holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> as soon as you hear the startup chime
2. Keep these keys down until you see a black screen with white text
3. Mount your drive by typing in `/sbin/mount -uw /` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
4. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing in 
   `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
5. Now reboot your MBP by typing in `reboot` and then pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key
6. Follow the prompts to complete the setup process and create a **new** admin account

Once you've done the above, try starting up and logging in as the new admin user and let me know what happens.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you also resetting this. Here’s how to do this on your particular MacBook Pro model:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again (i.e. a 2nd time) and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

Let me know what happens.

Comment: I will try it, but I don't understand the reason. As I mentioned, I erased the mac osx partition, and reinstalled the Sierra. Strictly speaking, the re-installation process was not completed because of the green screen problem. I had to finish all the settings ( account, language, etc) of a brand new system in the safe mode rather than in the normal mode.

Comment: Strictly speaking, doing this should not result in a different outcome if everything occurred as it should during the format and installation. But, doing this helps eliminate some possibilities regardless of the outcome.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the problem is still the same. Honestly, I always think my problem is related to this one:  https://www.apple.com/au/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: I've just added more to my answer. Please join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70981/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-jeff) as we try to sort this out.