# How to disable discrete GPU on MacBook Pro High Sierra permanently?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, high-sierra, gpu, apfs

yesterday I tried the solution for my MacBook Pro under **Sierra** from the forum under this link: [MacBook Pro: How to disable discrete GPU permanently from EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi)

I tried the following steps under **Sierra** with a good result *(I've got an **AMD graphic card** for NVIDIA change the code from AMD to NVIDIA)*:
Start in Single-User Mode (boot while pressing cmd+s)
Typed in the following command:

`sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`

`reboot`(reboot while pressing cmd+d)

Open the Terminal and use the following code:

`diskutil cs list` (find Logical Volume UUID: last item)

`diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume UUID` (UUID: from previous command)

`cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`

`mkdir AMD_Kexts`

`mv System/Library/Extensions/AMD*.* AMD_Kexts/`

`reboot`

Everything works fine know. Then I've updated the MacBook Pro to **High Sierra**. Everything installed fine. After I've restarted it didn't work and I tried the steps again. But the problem is that High Sierra on a SSD have the new **apfs** system. So after googling a time I found the code to change (I'm not a Terminal-Super-User).

So I started in Single-User-Mode by pressing cmd+s and typed in:

`sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`
`reboot`(reboot while pressing cmd+d)

Open the Terminal and use the following code:

`diskutil apfs list` (find the Logical Volume UUID: the first under the name **Volume** *Macintosh HD*)

`diskutil apfs unlockVolume UUID`

`cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`
The APFS Volume disk2s1 is already unlocked (mounted)
`mkdir AMD_Kexts`
mkdir: AMD_Kexts: File exists
`mv System/Library/Extensions/AMD*.* AMD_Kexts/`
mv: rename System/Library/Extensions/AMD1000Controller.kext to AMD_Kexts/AMD1000Controller.kext: Directory not empty
and more AMD Controllers with same message

Know I get the message the directory is not empty. After rebooting the MacBook Pro turns off after the half of loading. I tried the other Volumes also but the system doesn't start.

Have anybody an advise for me?

At the moment I install the system again to get back to a clean High Sierra.

Comment: What MacBook Pro are you using? 2010 or 2011 with the fauly graphic cards?

Comment: I'm using a MacBook Pro late 2011 with an AMD Radeon HD 6770M Graphic Card.

Comment: For the mid-2010 MacBook Pro with the nvidia GT330M GPU, there is a software patch (not over the EFI as you requested) that prevents the kernel panic: https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix //

Since you have another MBP model this patch might not work. Have a look to the information on MacRumors forums (espacially the post from the user "fabioroberto"): https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/gpu-kernel-panic-in-mid-2010-whats-the-best-fix.1890097/#post-23312990 //

The tool gfxCardStatus forces the use of the discrete or integrated GPU: https://gfx.io/

Comment: gfxCardStatus allows manual change of the GPU but will not prevent macOS from changing the GPU. This is first hand experience on a 15" 2010 MBP with this issue.