# Macbook Pro 2011 : After disabling the dGPU using Arch, normal boot hang halfway but working in safe boot

Tags: macos, terminal, gpu

I have followed all the instructions provided at 
[MacBook Pro: How to disable discrete GPU permanently from EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi) 
and I'm stuck at the following step:

> **3.1 Move AMD / NVIDIA kext files to a backup directory**
>
> Remove all the AMD (or NVIDIA, depending on your card) kext files in
>   the Terminal in Recovery Console. Trying to remove them in Single User
>   just gives sandbox errors, so don’t do it in Single User Mode! (the
>   one that you boot with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).
>
> - If you have FileVault, unlock it first.
> - Boot into Recovery (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) directly. If it fails then repeat step 2 and retry (dGPU could get active again after
>     booting into the os with AMD / NVIDIA kexts).
> - Start Terminal (This commands are for AMD. If you have NVIDIA, change accordingly)
>
>   `diskutil cs list` (find Logical Volume UUID: last item)
>     `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume UUID` (UUID: from previous command)
>     `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`
>     `mkdir AMD_Kexts`
>     `mv System/Library/Extensions/AMD*.* AMD_Kexts/`
>     `reboot`

The Result is: [image]

I'm using 2 hard disks, with no partition, a 120 Gb SSD for the system only and a 750 Gb drive for data. I actually don't understand the commands, I'm just following the instructions. After reboot it still hangs halfway.

Please, what should I do next?

Im using macbook pro 17" late 2011 with HD Graphics 3000/ AMD Radeon HD 6770M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're having is that you're not quite following the instructions correctly.

More specifically, you've run the `diskutil cs list` command correctly, but the purpose of running this command was to identify the Logical Volume UUID. And, the reason you needed to identify it was because you need to actually **use** it in the next command.

In other words, instead of entering:

`diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume UUID`

you need to enter

`diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 3F7CB47E-F743-4DBF-9BF1-10E574F85D13`

instead.

**NOTE:** This answer is designed to clarify how you needed to follow the instructions you're following. As your question only quotes a portion of those instructions, I cannot directly vouch for the accuracy or validity of the full instructions you're trying to follow.

Comment: i enter 
diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 3F7CB47E-F743-4DBF-9BF1-10E574F85D13
the result 3F7CB47E-F743-4DBF-9BF1-10E574F85D13 is not encrypted and its attached as disk3
and i continue with next same commands and the result is the same as the picture and still hang halfway

Comment: yes, the next command after diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 3F7CB47E-F743-4DBF-9BF1-10E574F85D13 is not encrypted and its attached as disk3
the rest has the same result as the pict.

Comment: Okay, well, that tells me you're not using FileVault (i.e. your drive is not encrypted and therefore there is no need for you to run that command). Or, at least the drive that UUID refers to isn't! So you should be able to just skip it - although, now that I'm looking at your screenshot, `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` is not going to work in your case because your drive isn't called *Macintosh HD*, it's called **Mindasari HD**. What happens if you run `cd /Volumes/Mindasari\ HD` instead? Also, are you using terminal from Recovery mode?

Comment: i typed cd /Volumes/Mindasari\ HD, seems to be ok (i assumed ok because no error respond, directly go to next blinking cursor), go to next mkdir command : ok, last command mv has the same result as pict and still hang halfway. Yes im using terminal recovery mode (cmnd + r) But is it correct that detected HD is my 750Gb Data HD instead of my 120Gb system data?

Comment: Well, what is your system drive? Your screenshot only shows one drive, not two. Instead of using `diskutil cs list`, try `diskutil list` instead. Do you then get two drives listed?

Comment: how can i attach the pict, it has long result when i hit diskutil list. It has 16 disks: 2 internal physical, 1 internal virtual, and the rest are disks image. my system in disk 0, and still the logical volume appears on Mindasari HD not Mindasari System

Comment: disk 0: internal physical : Mindasari System, disk1; image, disk 2: internal physical Mindasari HD, disk 3: internal virtual Mindasari HD, and the rest are disks image

Comment: I reinstall the system, system HD detected, follow all next steps and it works just fine! But i have small issue with  screen brightness adjuster disappear and keyboard brightness adjuster not working, i found many users has the same issue but no yet solution yet unless i have to reinstall and do all over again. Since I im happy with the result, its no big deal.  Thanks.

Comment: That's fantastic! :) Very glad you got it sorted! As for the screen and/or keyboard brightness issue, you can try resetting the NVRAM. To do this: Shut down your MBP, switch it back on on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds (your Mac will to restart during this time). Let go of the keys after you've heard the second startup chime.

Comment: Since i set my broken discrete GPU permanently disabled, im affraid resetting the NVRAM will set the problem back again. I've try resetting the NVRAM away before while boot still hang halfway, and it makes the GPU problem back. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you think after i moved all AMD Kext to different folder (through the step by step tutorial above) and succeed to make discrete GPU permanently disabled wlll not be affected by resetting the NVRAM?