# Disable dual Graphic and use only Intel card

Tags: startup

My Mac Book Pro is now stuck after Apple logo screen on a grey screen and after hours of search I found the problem is in my graphic card (this issue happen after updating to High Sierra).

So  I need to disable the second VGA

I tried with

```
/sbin/fsck -fy /
/sbin/mount -uw /
mkdir /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
cd /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* .
mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* .
touch /System/Library/Extensions
exit
```

but I got an error :

```
operation not permitted
```

any idea to fix this or at least disable SIP ?

**Notes**

I am not able to boot to any GUI neither by safe mode boot nor verbose mode or even recovery mode,  so I need to do it via terminal

I am only able to boot via single user mode

Comment: try Sudo Command if there is permission error !

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: try to reboot your mac and press ⌘+R when booting up (It Disables SIP System Integrity protection). Then go into Utilities > Terminal and type the following commands:

csrutil disable
reboot

Comment: recovery boot failed

Comment: Reset Smc And Pram and Nvram After That go

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8092332 Follow These Steps  and if after that it dosent boot than clean install of os is the option

Comment: After which of the steps you've tried did you get the "operation not permitted" error?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to disable SIP is to go in through the recovery partition and disable it from there, so unfortunately I don't think that will be an option for you with the current state of the machine.

I would take a look at the answer for this question here:
[MacBook Pro How To Disable Discrete GPU Permanently from EFI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi)

Booting into a different OS is probably going to be your best chance at success. Hope that helps!