# LCD model number or disabling discrete GPU for MacBook Pro 15 Retina 2012-2013

Tags: display, hardware, gpu

While trying to replace the battery, I must have damaged certain connection to the discrete gpu. Whenever trying to use discrete gpu, the computer would freeze.

After trying to reset VRAM, it basically won't boot anymore. (There's a 5% chance of booting by juggling around reset VRAM and unplugging boards.)

I would love to fix it if possible, probably by permanently disabling the discrete gpu in some way, but not giving too much hope.

Rather I will probably just reuse my screen as external display.

---

#### So, do anyone know what's the lcd model number for it so I can get a controller board for it?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd at least reset the SMC, as you've changed hardware, & check if you jogged a connection before giving up entirely. Blowing the NVRAM almost never fixes anything, but after any hardware change, resetting the SMC is always a valid option. https://support.apple.com/HT201295

Comment: @Tetsujin resetting SMC pretty much make it worse everytime. It just make it go to the "Your computer restarted because of a problem..." screen, and won't get out without couple more hours of juggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the LCD panel model number from the command line as it's not stored in firmware as part of the monitor's EDID.

For example, I had to replace the the LCD of my 27" iMac due to an unfortunate incident involving a disobedient child and a fidget spinner.  The model number for the panel was "LM270WQ1" where as the Apple PN# was "661-7169." Those numbers aren't present in any of the EDID data.  See below

Using the `system_profiler` command:

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType 
Displays:
    iMac:
      Display Type: LCD
      Resolution: 2560 x 1440 (QHD/WQHD - Wide Quad High Definition)
      UI Looks like: 2560 x 1440
      Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
      Connection Type: Internal
    DELL U2312HM:
      Resolution: 1080 x 1920
      UI Looks like: 1080 x 1920 @ 60 Hz
      Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Display Serial Number: T9MJ318O630L
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: 90
      Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
      Connection Type: Thunderbolt/DisplayPort
```

Using the `ioreg` command to get EDID

```
$ ioreg -lw0 -r -c "IODisplayConnect" -n "display0" -d 2 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6

s@L036"
q8-@X,E
T9MJ318O630L
DELL U2312HM
```

Neither have the actual *panel* info model because that's typically not put in by the display manufacturer.  For this, you need to (unfortunately) disassemble the display and get the LCD panel model off the back.  I recently replaced the LCD in a Mid-2007 MacBook (white) and it was imperative that I replace it with a compatible panel.  I was inadvertently sent a panel for a later MacBook (2008) and while it physically fit and the LVDS connectors were compatible, the panel simply didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the panel model number from the command line:

`ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6`

For me it's the third line:

```
$ ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayEDID | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
������
Color LCD
LP133WQ6-SJA4
```

More info at [OSXDaily - Find Out Type and Model of LCD Panel in an iMac, MacBook, MacBook Pro, etc](https://osxdaily.com/2010/07/28/find-out-what-model-lcd-panel-in-your-imac-macbook-macbookpro/)

Comment: But I can’t get to command line without booting it up, or can I?

Comment: Have you looked at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi ?

Comment: I just tried that, and the other link you commented earlier. Couldn't get it to work tho. I was able to get into safe mode after changing nvram, but after deleting kext files, it won't work anymore.

Comment: And using the command line in safe mode only output: `??????` and `Color LCD` without the model number

Comment: That gives you Apple's info for the *whole assembly*, not the panel.  And that info is not guaranteed to be there.  EDID data is haphazard at best.