# Disable MacBook Pro discrete GPU for specific apps

Tags: macbook-pro

**Is there a way to prevent certain apps from switching the active GPU to the discrete graphics card?**

---

I tried looking in System Preferences but there's only a setting to use the discrete GPU all the time.

[MacBook Pro: How to disable discrete GPU permanently from EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi?rq=1) I read this question and its answers, but it's about disabling the discrete GPU permanently and not per app.

I want GarageBand to stop using the discrete GPU on my MacBook Pro, to save battery life and reduce fan noise.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best answer is [gSwitch](https://codyschrank.github.io/gSwitch/).

What you could do is use Automator to run the cli command of switch to discrete "--discrete" when GarangeBand is opened and switch to "--dynamic" or close the app when GarageBand is closed.